# Можно ли сделать так, чтобы stl::vector разместил свой буфер не в куче, а в стеке?

Tags: c++, stl

Собственно вопрос относится не только к stl::vector, а ко всем контейнерам stl. Например, если я знаю, что вектор (или другой контейнер) будет маленький, я хочу разместить его в стеке, чтобы избежать затрат времени на обращение к куче. В структурах типа такой затраты времени на обращение к куче будут существенными:

```
for (i1=0;i1!=1000000;++i1){
for (i2=0;i2!=1000000;++i2){
for (i3=0;i3!=1000000;++i3){
for (i4=0;i4!=1000000;++i4){
for (i5=0;i5!=1000000;++i5){

stl::vector<char>(256) vec;
//здесь какая-то работа c vec

}
}
}
}
}
```

UPD1:

Пусть у меня максимальный размер вектора 256, но я хочу, чтобы там на этом месте (в стеке) был и вектор размером 10, который я потом увеличу до 256 (или уменьшу с 256 до 10). С простым вектором, размещенным в стеке, такое вполне возможно. А как насчет stl? Как мне разместить буфер stl::vector там, где я хочу?

UPD2:

> И перенеся контейнер по вне цикла оно будет работать так же быстро.

Не всегда можно перенести контейнер вне цикла. Например, в таком примере:

```
void fun(int size){
stl::vector<char>(size) vec;
//здесь какая-то работа c vec
}

for (i1=0;i1!=1000000;++i1){
for (i2=0;i2!=1000000;++i2){
for (i3=0;i3!=1000000;++i3){
for (i4=0;i4!=1000000;++i4){
for (i5=0;i5!=1000000;++i5){

fun(256);

}
}
}
}
}
```

UPD3:

> Обращение к стеку быстрее, чем к куче, ибо стек обычно находится в
>   кеше.

Не потому обращение к стеку быстрее, что стек находится в кеше. А потому, что обращение к стеку это всего лишь индексация регистра текущего стекового кадра. А обращение к куче (занятие и освобождение буфера) это системный вызов на 1000+ команд. Так что даже если вся куча сидит в кеше, то обращение к ней на три порядка медленнее, чем обращение к стеку.

UPD4:

> Можно передать в аллокатор буфер, расположенный на стеке, который
>   будет использоваться алокатором в качестве арены.

Так, наверное, можно сделать. Но тут есть проблемы:

1. Чтобы грамотно написать такой аллокатор, надо прошерстить весь код stl::vector (а может и не только его) и понять, когда вызывается аллокатор. Это задача нетривиальная. Кроме того, при смене транслятора или при выходе следующей версии транслятора и следующей версии stl никто не гарантирует, что реализация stl::vector останется такой же и придется снова разбираться в коде stl.
2. Даже если сделать аллокатор пустым, он все равно будет вызываться при работе, то есть занимать время по сравнению с обычным буфером на стеке.
3. Давно бы должны были написать такой аллакатор/аллокаторы для работы stl на стеке. Но что-то не видать Красной Армии.
4. Чтобы полноценно работать со всеми возможностями stl::vector, аллокаторы для всего остального, что есть в stl, тоже надо переписывать для работы на стеке. Для алгоритмов, итераторов и прочего.

UPD5:

> простенький аллокатора, которому не нужно уметь в многопоточность,
>   уметь переживать fork, уметь бороться с сегментацией, и т.д,

При выполнении метода std::vector::insert будет вызван аллокатор (хотя бы и пустой). Вместе с тем при размещении буфера в стеке этого делать не надо. Вот вам и penalty performance. Вместе с тем концепция STL утверждает, что penalty performance в STL нет.

Comment: В стеке нет средств перевыделения памяти. Ваш размер фиксирован? Ваш размер является константой времени компиляции? Тогда вам просто нужен `std::array<char, 256>`.

Comment: @AnT А разве std::array размещает свой буфер в стеке? Судя по всему, std::array тоже размещает свой буфер в куче. Кроме того, вопрос относится не только к вектору, а ко всем контейнерам stl.

Comment: Ну перепишите соответствующим образом аллокатор...

Comment: В таком варианте затраты скорее будет не на обращение к куче, а на переаллокацию памяти. И перенеся контейнер по вне цикла оно будет работать так же быстро.

Comment: Нет. `std::array` - агрегат, т.е. плоский одноуровневый объект. Никакого буфера в куче у него быть не может. Он весь целиком и полностью располагается там, где вы его определили.

Comment: @Harry А разве можно переписать аллокатор так, чтобы место выделялось в стеке?

Comment: @pepsicoca1 Можно. Только я же не написал о том, в стеке какой функции и какова будет продолжительность жизни выделенной памяти... :)

Comment: @Harry Доступа к стеку на уровне языка в С++ нет. Так что аллокатор придется на ассемблере писать, если вообще это возможно. Но даже и в этом случае увеличение или уменьшение вектора или другого контейнера stl (с буфером, размещенным в стеке) будет проблемой.

Comment: @pepsicoca1 не обязательно. Можно передать в аллокатор буфер, расположенный на стеке, который будет использоваться алокатором в качестве арены.

Comment: А какой в этом смысл? Обращение к стеку быстрее, чем к куче, ибо стек обычно находится в кеше. Если в стеке размещать большие объекты, он перестанет влезать в кеш и обращение к нему будет занимать столько же времени, сколько и к куче. Поэтому магия написанием аллокатора, который будет выделять места на стеке никакого элеута не даст. В памяти выделенная память и параметры функции (которые при вызове функции в кеше) окажутся далеко, и всё равно при работе с контейнером придётся лезть в память.

Comment: Конкретно в вашем примере, проблема, что пересоздаётся вектор, а для этого на кучу выделяется память, что долго. В качаете варианта можно написать аллокатора, который резервирует память на куче, или просто вынести вектор за цикл.

Comment: @Chorkov Именно :) Но есть еще нестандартный вариант, доступный почти везде - использовать `alloca()`.

Comment: @pepsicola1, простенький аллокатора, которому не нужно уметь в многопоточность, уметь переживать fork, уметь бороться с сегментацией, и т.д, а только в конструкторе выделить себе арену, в деструкторе стереть, при allocate() выдавать ссылку на начало арены и иметь функцию, которая очищает арену очень просто. Дальше читать описание стандарта std::vector. Я бы ожидал, что за размеры арены он не вылезет ни при каких условиях.

Comment: Читать код std::vector, для анализа как написать аллокатор - путь в никуда. Нужно прочитать документацию (стандарт C++) или статьи посещенные аллокаторам, например https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Allocator . Все контейнеры имеют единый набор требования к аллокаторам, поэтому его можно будет применять всюду один и тот же. Пример реализации стекового аллокатора: https://howardhinnant.github.io/stack_alloc.html , https://howardhinnant.github.io/short_alloc.h